# How to do an action when Eureka Slider is released?

Tags: ios, swift, netflix-eureka, eureka-forms

I have a `SliderRow` and I would like to take an action but only if the slider is released.

The `.onChange` does the action every time the user slides a bit (of course).
The `.onCellHighlightChanged` does not work for the `SliderRow`.

An option for `.onSliderReleased` would be great ;)

DoI  have another options in meanwhile?

```
<<< SliderRow("Barrel") { row in
                    row.title = "Barrel"
                    row.value = Float(UserDefaultsManager.Barrel())
                    row.steps = 19
                    row.displayValueFor = { row in
                       return "\(Int(row ?? 0)) bbl"
                    }

                }.cellSetup { cell, row in
                    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(systemName: "antenna.radiowaves.left.and.right")
                    cell.slider.minimumValue = 5
                    cell.slider.maximumValue = 100

                }.onChange { row in
                    let Barrel = Double(row.value ?? 50)
                    UserDefaultsManager.set(Barrel: Barrel)

                    ConnectionManager.reconnect()

                }
```

Comment: I suggest you abandon Eureka altogether ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
cell.slider.isContinuous = false
```

is half of the way, tanks for that
but it also disables the value update of the slider
so the user have "to guess" what value will be set

got it working with

```
cell.slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.sliderDidEndSliding), for: [.touchUpInside, .touchUpOutside])
```

and

```
@objc private func sliderDidEndSliding() {
   //do some magic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a property [`isContinuous`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uislider/1621340-iscontinuous) in `UISlider` which controls the behavior.

```
.cellSetup { cell, row in
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(systemName: "antenna.radiowaves.left.and.right")
    cell.slider.minimumValue = 5
    cell.slider.maximumValue = 100
    cell.slider.isContinuous = false
```